# How can I correct this script to map clicks to number keys?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a 4 button mouse and am trying to manage complex, extensive MMO spell rotations quickly by mapping a combination of modified clicks to the 1-8 keys.

My goal is:

- While holding down (3rd Mouse Button) XButton1, Left Click = 1 Key.
- While holding down (3rd Mouse Button) XButton1, Right Click = 2 Key.
- While holding down (4th Mouse Button) XButton2, Left Click = 3 Key.
- While holding down (4th Mouse Button) XButton2, Right Click = 4 Key.
- While holding down (3rd Mouse Button) XButton1 and Shift, Left Click = 5 Key.
- While holding down (3rd Mouse Button) XButton1 and Shift, Right Click = 6 Key.
- While holding down (3rd Mouse Button) XButton2 and Shift, Left Click = 7 Key.
- While holding down (3rd Mouse Button) XButton2 and Shift, Right Click = 8 Key.

---

```
XButton1 & LButton::
Send 1
XButton1 & RButton::
Send 2
XButton2 & LButton::
Send 3
XButton2 & RButton::
Send 4
XButton1 & +LButton::
Send 5
XButton1 & +RButton::
Send 6
XButton2 & +LButton::
Send 7
XButton2 & +RButton::
Send 8
```

I'm getting an invalid hotkey error at line 9. I'm completely new to AutoHotkey so this may be all wrong, I'm not sure.

Comment: your code would misbehave. Either put the hotkey  statements in a line each (woxxom did in his answer), or finish every hotkey with a `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You've used `+` to indicate a <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on that line 9 but the combokey notation allows exactly two physical keys to be paired. Solution: check the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key state manually with [GetKeyState](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm).
2. Put the hotkey command (`Send ...`) onto the same line as the hotkey declaration, otherwise all commands below will be executed until a `return` statement is encountered or to the end of the script (all `send` commands in your case).

```ahk
XButton1 & LButton::SendEither(1, 5)
XButton1 & RButton::SendEither(2, 6)
XButton2 & LButton::SendEither(3, 7)
XButton2 & RButton::SendEither(4, 8)

SendEither(key, keyShift) {
    Send % GetKeyState("Shift","P") ? keyShift : key
}
```